# Is there any alternative way of installing R packages except install.packages

Tags: r

I am trying to install `RSclient` on the server machine but there are some dependency issues coming in installing through `install.packages('RSclient',,'http://www.rforge.net/')`. The dependencies are mostly 32 bit and hence I am a bit confused whether they will create issue with 64 bit version of same dependencies present on my server. Is there any other way I can get this done instead of `install.packages()`? I have installed `RSclient` on my local machine so **is it possible I can take the library files installed and place them on the server and they will work correctly?** I can see `RSclient` on my machine at /home/lib.

Comment: Why not `install.packages` ?  You can always manually install each required dependency by downloading the zip files.

Comment: You might try `devtools::install_url`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft like I mentioned the dependencies are mostly 32 bit and hence I was confused as I already have 64 bit versions of those dependencies on my server

Comment: You can do `R CMD INSTALL` on the command-line or via a `system()` call.

Comment: @Thomas the dependencies are 32 bit and I have 64 version of these available on my server. Will it create issue with two version of same dependency?